# Accessing class with a switch menu

Tags: java

I'm self learning OOP at this point and have come to a stop due to this.

To the point. 
I'm creating a menu with a switch statement. 
Case 1 populates an object with data and sends it to its constructor.

In Case 2 I want it to show all of the relevant data in the object created with Case 1 (using a toString()) but in case 2 it just says "Customer cannot be resolved to a variable".

I think case 2 does not know that Customer class has already been instantiated (in case 1) and therefore I cannot access the customer.toString() method.

Answer (score 0):

A switch statement is basically an if statement and in your case when case 2 is executed case 1 is not called at all. So the object is not at all being created when case 2 is invoked. The best way will be to either create the object before the switch call or if you want to go ahead with your method then create the object within case 2 as well.

Comment: Thanks! So I can only access that object WITHIN the same case 1?

Comment: I was trying to call methods from another case so that the UI could show different aspects of the object in different cases. For example case 2: showBill() and case 3: showProducts()

Comment: Yes if case 1 is invoked only case 1 gets called , and then in that case 1you can do anything.with the object. And check what ever you want.

Comment: So if you want that create an object before the switch call  and in the cases depending upong what you want to pass to call each method you pass like if input is 1 then call case 1 show bill method and if input is 2 do a different method call and this way you need not create objects again and again

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! This creates a ton more problems for me at this point.
Off-topic from now on.